# Ignoring Format of jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

how can i ignore the formatting and adding the classes that jQuerymobile creates? Is there any possibility to ignore them?

I would like to format an element with my own style.

I already tried adding `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;` in the pageInit and than adding `data-role="none"` on the element. But it didn't worked. I found that solution on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;` like you have already done in the `pageInit` function and then add `data-enhance="false"` instead of `data-role="none"`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It worked. Why `data-role="none"` worked for others and not for me?